# How to extract user profile from Planner (List tasks)?

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-planner

The flow/PowerAutomate is as follows

PowerAutomateFlow

[image]

1. Choose the GroupID and PlanID from Workspaces for List Task step
2. Get plan details: PlanID = first(outputs('List_tasks')?['body/value'])?['planId']
3. Tasks:
   From = outputs('List_tasks')?['body/value']
   Map: Assignments = items()?['_assignments']

For Each Tasks

[image]

The reason to extract user profile/email from user ID is to create Metrics. Also, when trigger 'When new tasks is created' is used, it easy to extract the user profile from valueassignment but the use case, we can only use ListTasks as trigger can be manual.

Although below reference shares how to extract, extracting required part within a loop from JSON has become tricky. Please help us.
Reference: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Exporting-the-Assigned-To-user-ID-from-Planner/td-p/177310
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Listing-tasks-ASSIGNED-TO-a-certain-user-from-Planner-in/m-p/1783631#M452392

Reference: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Exporting-the-Assigned-To-user-ID-from-Planner/td-p/177310
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Listing-tasks-ASSIGNED-TO-a-certain-user-from-Planner-in/m-p/1783631#M452392

###### Update

Basically, to grab user ID from the Tasks step

[image: Snapshot of Raw output of Tasks]

## Update about concatenating users for each task

User profile left unchanged: `items('ForEachTasks')?['Assignments']?[0]?['userId']`

[Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vwogw.png)

Comment: What’s the tricky part?

Comment: Not sure what to enter in "Get User Profile (V2)", the filed the User field with the expressions shared in the screenshot but it didnt yield in extracting email ID of the assignee of the task

Comment: Can you show us example data that is being used in the expressions and that is coming out of the relevant steps involved?

Comment: Sure Skin, I added an update. In the snapshot update, I added the first example in which assignments were assigned to 2 users hence 2 user ID is seen for the assignment. How to grab both of them in the Get User Profile ?

Comment: In future, paste it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `'_assignments'` is an array you will need to target the first one. Try something similar to:

```js
items('ForEachTasks')?['Assignments']?[0]?['userId']
```

Comment: I accepted your answer and it works. How can we alter the expression when we have no user or more than 1 user assigned to the same task ?

Comment: Depends what you are going to do with them. You could add a `Apply To Each` step on `items('ForEachTasks')?['Assignments']`

Comment: Basically this output would be fed to Scorecard/metrics "email field"

Comment: Then yeah, you will need to add the `Apply to Each` action to loop through and get the email address of each. In the loop you'd want to add the email address to an Array variable. Then `join` the array with a semi-colon, then add to the Goal email field.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I just shared the screenshot of the changes I made to concatenate the users with Join but Join fails with following error: `InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Join' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'Error setting value to 'From' on 'Microsoft.Azure.Workflows.Data.Operations.JoinActionInput'.'.`

Comment: As mentioned earlier, you need an Array variable to append to. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXBkX.png

Comment: Thanks Sam, Since I was not sure which expression you used for `Get User profile` expression and input for `ForEachAssigned` , I replicated it and it works if the tasks is assigned to single user because `items('ForEachAssigned')?['Assignments']?[0]?['userId']` grabs just the 1st userId *only* and as tasks can be assigned to single or many user, we cannot define specifically the integer e.g. `items('ForEachAssigned')?['Assignments']?[1]?['userId']`. Therefore wondering if there is way !

Comment: Also, if currentItem of the `ForEachTasks` is used for inputting `ForEachAssignment `, it throws an error: `ExpressionEvaluationFailed. The execution of template action 'ForEachAssigned' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@items('ForEachTask')' is of type 'Object'. The result must be a valid array.`. If fed the same input as `ForEachTasks`, the loop runs the same number of times but grabs **only the first userID from each assignments** and the rest are ignored. Hence while joining the emails at the last step, it has mismatches in the assigned users.

Comment: The expression for the `ForEachAssigned` is `items('ForEachTasks')?['Assignments']` - remember it is an array, so you feed that in, dropping the `[0]` part, which is used to get first item from the array. The expression for `Get user profile` would be: `items('ForEachAssigned')?['userId']`